# How to show name in the url instead id in Cakephp?

Tags: url, cakephp, controller

I want to customize my url in cakephp

```
http://localhost/cantq4tickets/events/event_detail/1
```

instead of 1 (event_id) in url i want event name ex. birthday party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your events db table add field 'slug' VARCHAR (255)

In your Event model add before save method:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    parent::beforeSave();
        $name_to_slug = Inflector::slug($this->data['Event']['name'], $replacement = '-');
        $this->data['Event']['slug'] = strtolower($name_to_slug);

    return true;    
}
```

In your router

```
Router::connect('/events/*', array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'details'));
```

links in your views:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($event['Event']['name'],array('controller'=>'events','action'=>'details',$event['Event']['slug'])); ?>
```

in your EventsController::details($slug=null)  **findBySlug**

Answer (score 0):

You are after `Routing` which gives you some flexibility in making the URLs pretty. I'd suggest reading the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) first and then perhaps going over some of these examples: http://lecterror.com/articles/view/advanced-routing-with-cakephp-one-example